# password problem when feeding a remote file into diff

Tags: ssh, pipe, password, diff, process-substitution

When I want to compare a local file with a remote file, any of these usually works:

```
$ ssh remote cat file | diff file -
$ diff file <(ssh remote cat file)
```

However, sometimes (especially when the password is needed) they fail like this:

```
$ ssh remote cat file | diff file -
1,162d0
< ...
< ...
Password:
```

Here, `diff` doesn't wait for `ssh` to complete and considers the second file empty. It is only after `diff` is finished that `ssh` asks for the password, but it is too late.

```
$ diff file <(ssh remote cat file)
Password: 
Password:       # asking again after a few seconds
#&%Pasword:     # the typed raw password leaks into the terminal
user@remote's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
user@remote's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
user@remote's password:
Received disconnect from XXX.XX.XX.XX: 2: Too many authentication failures for user
1,162d0
< ...
< ...
```

This time, `ssh` asks for the password, but the typed password is echoed back to the terminal, and `ssh` doesn't get it. Finally, `ssh` fails and `diff` continues with an empty second file.

Can you explain why these are happening, or what's happening in detail *under the hood*?

Comment: I can't explain or reproduce this behavior. What OS are you running, what shell, what version? If you move your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc` or other relevant file out of the way, does it make a difference? P.S. Mount the remote directory with [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), then call `diff` on the two regular files.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, bash 4.2.24(1)-release.

Comment: It seems that `alias diff='colordiff'` messed up with the redirection; not using the alias solves the problem for the pipeline case. Thank you!
However, the process substitution case remains the same. Even `cat <(ssh remote cat file)` fails in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run ssh first:

```
ssh remote 'cat file' | cat
```

ssh gets your controlling terminal as stdin, so you can type your password in with no problems.

When you use bash's [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), stdin remains connected to the first command, and the subprocess's output pipe gets passed to the first command as an argument:

```
cat <(ssh remote 'cat file')
```

If the ssh negotiation succeeded, `/dev/fd/63` will be a pipe containing the output of `ssh remote 'cat file'`.

This can be demonstrated with the following command:

```
$ echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

The important part of this is that **your terminal is connected to `cat`'s stdin, not `ssh`'s**. When this runs, `cat` gets a command-line argument like `/dev/fd/63`.  Therefore, cat ignores stdin altogether; however, it is still connected to the cat process, and not `ssh`, so your password goes nowhere.

If you want to change this, you will need to run `ssh` first, and pipe the output to `diff`, as you have already demonstrated above:

```
ssh remote 'cat file' | diff file -
```